# Implementing rules for a Bishop in Chess

Tags: java

I'm trying to think of a way to efficiently and neatly determine whether a valid move is being made with a bishop in chess.

The piece will be moved from srcX,srcY to dstX,dstY

This is part of one of my ideas:

```
    if(srcX < dstX && srcY < dstY) {
        // Moving towards the top right of the board
                        // Determine the decrease in X coordinate
            int deltaX = dstX-srcX;

            // If the move is valid, the Y coordinate will have decreased by the same number as X
            int validY = dstY-deltaX;

            if(validY == srcY) {
                validMove = true;
            }

    }
```

but it's going to be a bit long winded, doing that for ever corner.. Can anyone think of a nicer way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would break it up into two steps.

1) Is it a valid destination?
2) Are there obstructions?

The first is easy to calculate. Since a bishop can only move diagonals the deltaX and deltaY must be equal.

So, `if( abs(srcX-dstX) == abs(srcY-dstY) )`

That rules out logically invalid moves.

Then it is a simple matter iterating through the positions in between as you have done to check for obstructions.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a diagonal the x and y move shoudl be the same, so...

```
return Math.abs(srcx - dstx) == Math.abs(srcy - dsty);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you compare the absolute value of `srcx - dstx` and `srcy - dsty`?

Comment: It all depends on the coordinate system, but yes :P

Comment: It is not dependent on the co-ordinate system at all... You are comparing the magnitudes of the x and y components of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The move is valid if:

```
      Destx-Desty = SourceX - SourceY      OR 

16 - DestX- DestY = SourceX - SourceY
```